# Continuity of implicit function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I find a proof of the following theorem in A.N. Kolmogorov and S.V. Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* (pp. 492-493 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)):

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach spaces, $U$ a neighbourhood of point
>   $(x_0,y_0)\in X\times Y$ and $F$ a map of $U$ into $Z$ having the
>   following properties:
>
> 1. $F$ is continuous in point $(x_0,y_0)$.
> 2. $F(x_0,y_0)=0$.
> 3. Partial [Fréchet] derivative $F'_y(x,y)$ exists in $U$ and is continuous in point $(x_0,y_0)$, and operator $F'_y(x_0,y_0)$ has
>      bounded inverse.
>
> Then [...] there exist $\varepsilon>0,\delta>0$ and a map
>   $$y=f(x)\quad\quad(1)$$defined for $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$ and continuous
>   in point $x_0$ such that every couple $(x,y)$, for which
>   $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$ and $y=f(x)$, verify equation
>   $$F(x,y)=0,\quad\quad(2)$$and, vice versa, every couple satisfying
>   equation $(2)$ and conditions $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$,
>   $\|y-y_0\|\le\varepsilon$ verifies equation $(1)$.

In a following corollary the book says that *it is easy to show* that if $F$ is continuous in $U$ then $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $x_0$. I find this last statement interesting, but I cannot prove it to myself. Could anybody explain why $f$ is continuous in some neighbourhood of $x_0$ under the hypothesis of the continuity of $F$ in $U$? I heartily thank you!

Comment: The assumption on $F$ implies that $F'_y(x,y)$ has a bounded inverse (with a controlled norm) for all $(x,y)$ in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$. Then, the *proof* of the theorem should give that $f$ is continuous at $x$ for all $x$ ina neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: @Etienne If I correctly understood if $F$ is continuous on $U$ and $(x,y)\mapsto F'_y(x,y)$ exists in $U$ and is continuous in $(x_0,y_0)$ with $[F'_y(x_0,y_0)]^{-1}\in\mathscr{L}(Z,Y)$ then, for all $(x,y)$ in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, $[F'_y(x,y)]^{-1}\in\mathscr{L}(Z,Y)$: OK? How can it be proved? How does it follow that $f$ is continuous on a neighbourhood of $x_0$? I've tried to use some majorations from Kolmogorov-Fomin's proof, but my trials lead nowhere... $\infty$ thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, you correctly understood. This is because the set of invertible operators is open in $\mathcal L(Y,Z)$. For the second part, it seems to me that if you replace 3 by something like "$F'_y(x,y)$ exists and is invertible in neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, with inverse bounded by some constant C", then the proof of KF still shows existence and continuity of $f$ at $x_0$. Then you can *apply* this result (if true) to any point in the neighbourhood where "3 modified" holds.

Comment: @Etienne Really interesting. Therefore openness guarantees that $F'_y(x',y')$ exists in any point $(x',y')$ in a neighbourhood $V\subset U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ (no assumption of continuity of $F$ in $U$  until now). Therefore, if we replace $F$ with $F-F(x',y')$ we get a unique function $f'$ satisfying $F(x'',f(x''))=F(x',y')$ for $\|x''-x'\|<\delta'$, but I'm not sure this will lead me to see the continuity of $f$... I $\infty$-ly thank you again!